# How to set ag-grid headerName to translate

Tags: ag-grid, angular-translate

When i set headerName or displayName with "$filter('translate')('HostName')", like following

```
export default (($filter, modalHelper, $translate) => [{
    displayName:$filter('translate')('HostName'),
    headerCellFilter: 'translate',
    headerFilter:'translate',
    field: 'name',
    width: 130,
    filter: 'text'}]


const en = {
    'HEADLINE': 'This is a test',
    'HostName': 'This is Host Name',
    'IPAddress': 'IP Address'}

export default {
   en
}


const cn = {
    'HEADLINE': '这是一个测试',
    'HostName': '主机名',
    'IPAddress': 'IP 地址'
}

export default {
   cn
}
```

headerName just can show once，can not dynamic  change, when i run changeLanguage function, like bellow

```
function changeLanguage() {
  $translate.use($scope.lang)
  })
}
$scope.langs = ['English', '中文（简体）'];
$scope.lang = '中文（简体）';

$translateProvider.translations('English', translateEN.en)
  .translations('中文（简体）', translateCN.cn)
  .preferredLanguage('中文（简体）') // 默认 EN
```

If there have any solution to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Seems](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#header-value-getters) that it could be done with `headerValueGetter`

> Use `headerValueGetter` instead of `colDef.headerName` to allow dynamic header names.

inside `headerValueGetter` function you can handle translations

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change the `headerName` manually.

There's a function named `refreshHeader()`, [here's an example from the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#changing-column-headers).

Or, you can reload your entire columns definitions [with `setColumnDefs()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/), if it's easier.